# How can I change this to just array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have written this code but I have to change this from saving in list to saving in array. So that every animal in my txt file should have its position in the array. There is 10 animals. Anyone can help?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String line = "";
    int count = 0;

    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Zoo.txt"));
        while (line != null) {
            count++;
            line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            if (count == 3 || count % 3 == 1 && !line.equals("1") && 
     !line.equals("5") && !line.equals("10"));
                arrayList.add(line);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayList.toArray()));

        br.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File not found.");
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot read this file.");
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Why is an `ArrayList` not what you want? You can also get the index of elements from an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @versaces Count the number of lines in your text file, declare array of that size, input each line of text into that index of array.

Comment: @Mark I want everything that is in the list be converted into simple array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Ryan suggestion :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String line = "";
        int count = 0;
        int countLineNumber=0; //to count line numbers 
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Zoo.txt"));
            while (line != null) {
                count++;
                line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                if (count == 3 || count % 3 == 1 && !line.equals("1") && 
         !line.equals("5") && !line.equals("10"));
                    arrayList.add(line);
                countLineNumber++;
            }
            //System.out.println(countLineNumber);

            br.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found.");
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot read this file.");
        }

        //getting elements from arayList saving them into a array 
        String[] array=new String[countLineNumber];
        for(int i=0;i<countLineNumber;i++){
            array[i]=arrayList.get(i);
        }

        //display element in array
        for(int k=0;k<array.length;k++){
        System.out.println(array[k]);

        }
}
```

Comment: After running your code, in the console I see the list of my text file.

Answer (score 1):

With Java8+, you could do :

```
Path path = Paths.get("Zoo.txt");
String[] animals = Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset()).toArray(String[]::new);
```